# Problem parsing unicode escape in a Java 6 String literal...?

Tags: java, unicode, java-6

Why does this compile in java 6 (Sun 1.6.0_16):

```
System.out.println("\u000B");
```

... but not this:

```
System.out.println("\u000A");
```

On this program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
  System.out.println("\u000A");
  }
}
```

I get a

```
Test.java:3: unclosed string literal
System.out.println("\u000A");
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that the Unicode replacement is done very early in compilation. Unicode escapes aren't just valid in strings and character literals (as other escape sequences such as `\t` are) - they're valid *anywhere* in code. They're described in a different area of the spec - [section 3.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.3) rather than [section 3.10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6); only the latter is about *character and string literal* escape sequences.

Basically, read section 3 of the spec for more details on lexical structure :)

So your code was *actually* equivalent to:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
  System.out.println("
");
  }
}
```

... which clearly isn't valid code. For carriage return and line feed, basically it's best to use the "\r" and "\n" escape sequences.

Personally I view this handling of Unicode escaping as a flaw in Java, but there's not a lot we can do about it now :(

Comment: Somebody could put up video tutorial serial like Khan Academy based on Jon Skeet's answers. Respect.

Answer (score 3):

> Unicode escapes are expanded prior to lexical analysis.
> The fact that the Unicode escape appears within a string literal is irrelevant.
> See JLS 3.2.

- [Resource](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4241780)

Answer (score 1):

it's because \u000a = \n and the compiler process the java source in order to convert it into tokens, so you cannot use that unicode character in your code. The same for \u000d=\r

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, to avoid the prepocessing we could solve it by changing the line in:

```
System.out.println((char)10);
```

The limitation is that by being a `CHAR`, it's extension will be from 0 to 255.